# Replace default local font

Tags: fonts, internationalization

Could someone tell me how to replace system default localization font? I mean when it time to render my language I want to use specific font instead of the one Ubuntu choice for me.

thz

Answer (score 2):

From the main GNOME menu go to, System > Preferences > Appearance, and look under the Fonts tab. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: No it is not, what I want to know is the how Ubuntu choice default font say for Janpan, Lao, Indian etc.

Comment: I thought it just used the appropriate unicode ranges of the font chosen there, but maybe I don't know enough about localization.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu silently and automatically falls back to different fonts to achieve full Unicode coverage of many languages.  The order of those fallbacks are defined in the **FontConfig** setting files under:

- `/etc/fonts/conf.d`

these configuration files (which are just plain text files) contain the default preference ordering for certain scripts and Unicode ranges, depending on what fonts are actually installed.s